# sequlize transaction rollback is not working for multiple items(node js)

Tags: node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

I have an array of object and I want an atomic transaction in sequelize.

```
updateCreatorDb(resultObj) {
return Promise.map(resultObj.rows, function (result: any) {
    return sequelize.transaction({ autocommit: false }).then(function (t) {
        return postgresService.updateByIdTrans(result.id, "user_transactions",
            { status: "sucess" }, t).then(function () {
                return postgresService.updateByIdTrans(result.to_user, "user",
                    { balance: sequelize.literal('balance+' + result.amount) }, t).then(function (data) {
                         t.commit();
                    }, function (error) {
                         t.rollback();
                    })
            }, function (error) {
                 t.rollback();
            });
    }); 
});
```

}

```
 updateByIdTrans(id: number, model: string, attributes, t:    Transaction): Promise<void> {
   let promise = new Promise<void>((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
     logger.info("updating table " + model);
   return models[model].update(attributes, { where: { id: id }, returning: true }, { transaction: t })
          .then((results) => {
            if (results.length > 0) {
              logger.info(`Updated Object with id ${id}.`);
              resolve(JSON.stringify(results[1][0]));
            } else {
              logger.info(`Object with id ${id} does not exist.`);
              resolve(JSON.stringify(`Object with id ${id} does not exist.`));
            }

          }).catch((error: Error) => {
            logger.error(error.message);
            reject(error);
          });
     });

return promise;
```

}

If 2nd update statement fails then I want to rollback first update statement also as they are using same transaction object and not committed until 2 nd update statement is success 
.with this code if I have an error in 2nd update statement then only 2nd update statement is rolled backed and first update statement get commited.

Comment: In the example you provided, you create new transaction at every loop of `.map()` method, so it gets commited every time the `update` is successful, so if the error occurs in `n` loop, all `n-1` transactions are commited and changes are saved in the database

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But here my issue is (n-1) should rollback if error come in (n-1) only

Comment: I understand now. I think that `updateByIdTrans` function source code would be useful in this case to solve your issue

Comment: updated please have a look